# IOS: NavigationController switch UIViewcontrollers , EXC_BAD_ACCESS EXC_I386_GPFLT error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When I tap button to pushViewController `ViewController` to `ViewController2`, 
First time is okay, when i return from `ViewController2` to `ViewController`,
the second click button to ViewController2 , 
occurred errer:`EXC_BAD_ACCESS EXC_I386_GPFLT`.

This is my ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    self.circleAnimator = [MaterialCircleAnimator new];

    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:event:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

#pragma mark - UINavigationControllerDelegate iOS7新增的2个方法
- (id) navigationController:(UINavigationController     *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:    (UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:    (UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush) {
        return self.circleAnimator;
    }else if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop){
        return self.circleAnimator;
    }else{ // UINavigationControllerOperationNone
        return nil;
    }
}

- (IBAction) buttonClick:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint position = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:sender];

    ViewController2 *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

    //convert to absolute position
    position = [self.button convertPoint:position toView:self.view];

    [self.circleAnimator setCenterPoint:position];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}

@end
```

This is my ViewController2.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@implementation ViewController2

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    self.circleAnimator = [MaterialCircleAnimator new];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickBack:event:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

#pragma mark - UINavigationControllerDelegate iOS7新增的2个方法
- (id) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush) {
        return self.circleAnimator;
    }else if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop){
        return self.circleAnimator;
    }else{ // UINavigationControllerOperationNone
        return nil;
    }
}

- (IBAction)clickBack:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint position = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:sender];
    //convert to absolute position
    position = [self.button convertPoint:position toView:self.view];
    [self.circleAnimator setCenterPoint:position];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

And This is my demo on Github:
https://github.com/TindleWei/MaterialCircleAnimation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to create a new instance of `viewController2` every time the button is tapped in `viewController`. You should instead keep it as a property in `viewController` and instantiate it only if its **nil**. So the getter of the property `secondViewController` inside `viewController` will look something like this:

```
- (ViewController2 *)secondViewController {
  if (_secondViewController != nil) {
    return _secondViewController;
  }
  _secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
  return _secondViewController;
}
```

Comment: The problem fixed.  I don't why the simple normal way can't work, but it works well. Thx anyway.